# Bidirectional One-To-One

Tags: grails

I have two domain classes:

```
class Contract {
    String refNo
}

class Attachment {
    byte[] data
    String mimeType
    String fileName
}
```

How can I set up the relationships so that I have both `contractInstance.attachment` and `attachmentInstance.contract`? I think this is bidirectional one-to-one but I'm not sure (one `Contract` has to have exactly one `Attachment`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Contract {
    Attachment attachment
}

class Attachment {
    static belongsTo = [contract: Contract]
}
```

This define a 1-to-1 relationship between the two, with Contract being the owner of the relationship. This means that if you save/delete a Contract the save/delete will cascade to the Attachment, but the inverse is not true.

Comment: This seems to work well, there is just one problem: `Attachment.findByContract(Contract.get(someId))` always returns `null`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work:

```
class Contract {
    Attachment attachment
}

class Attachment {
    Contract contract
}
```

Comment: As with most things there is more than one way to solve this.  I'd use DmitryB's solution.  Don's would work as well.  Or for a third option you could look at using hasOne: (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html).  I've never used the hasOne but it seems like it would work as well.